# Windows server GPO, how to force SSID connection if in range

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, group-policy, wifi

I have many wifi networks, but only one of these are suitable for domain computers of my windows 2016 domain.

Can I setup a GPO to force a particular SSID usage if in the range? Many times I found that users choosed the wrong network and then the wrong ssid became the prefered one.

I alread set up a GPO but this just add a profile in the SSID list and does nothing about connection priority.

[image]

Consider that all SSID signal power are the same because they are broadcast by the same antennas.

Comment: _Connect to available networks in the order of profiles listed below_...are you _sure_ this isn't a priority ordered list?

Comment: Maybe it is, but the seems that other SSIDs not listed in the GPO take more priority.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the add >> infrastructure and then enter your SSID there.

Check the following page for a video.

http://pc-addicts.com/gpo-wireless-settings-group-policy/